# drop down with spinner-can not find the id

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I am trying to create a drop down using Spinner but is running into a problem for quite long. I also went over [Good Developers Spinners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) also [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/spinner/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/) is a good example. But I have a problem and could not solve it. 
My main_activity.java

```
package com.example.dropdown;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
private Button button;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addItemsOnSpinner2();
    addListenerOnButton();
   addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();


}




// add items into spinner dynamically
  public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
      spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);



  }




private void addListenerOnButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




private void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">AndroidSpinner</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>   
    <string name="select">Choose a country</string>
    <string name="select2">Choose an item</string>
    <string name="button_label">Submit</string>

    <string-array name="country_array">
        <item>Greece</item>
        <item>United Kingdom</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>Turkey</item>
        <item>Poland</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and my activity_main.xml (layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/country_array"
    android:prompt="@string/select"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/select2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="227dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here, did I do anything wrong with naming

```
android:id="@+id/spinner2"
```

coz i m not able to find it by id in my main activity class. It is showing me following error:

> spinner2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

[image]

Comment: post the logcat error.

Comment: Are you getting run time error or compile time??

Comment: Hi, can you see the image , i just took a screenshot that spinner2 is said spinner2 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: since I have this error, I can not run the application.

Comment: Just clean and build your project and make sure u have set correct xml  layout to u r activity.

Comment: Hi sandy, thank you! After cleaning up the project, I had another error. Quite strange! I deleted the whole project from the workspace and re-build it and is working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Two spinners in the same view can be a little tricky, but it is do-able. Since I'm relatively new to android I've been a little reluctant to post an answer, but here it goes:

First, I usually use fragments within the activity, but either way I believe you can use the LayoutInfater class to inflate the layout. Something like this in your activity:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.id.yourlayout, null);
```

Pass the view to your spinnner methods:

```
 getSpinner1(view);
 getSpinner2(view);
```

Now the tricky part. You call the above methods with detail similar to this:

```
public void getStateSpinner(View view) {    
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.YourSpinner1Id);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.spinner1_array, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setVisibility(0);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner1OnItemSelectedListener());
}

public void getStateSpinner(View view) {    
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.YourSpinner2Id);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.spinner2_array, 
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setVisibility(0);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner2OnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

Then I used 2 static inner classes to implement the OnItemSelectedListener interface twice:

```
public static class Spinner1OnItemSelectedListener implements   OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner1Variable = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

}

That's about it.

As I said, I used fragments, so your implementation will be somewhat different. Since you are using an activity, I did substitute 'this' in a couple of places where I used getActivity().

I hope this enough to get you going in the right direction.

Take care,

Doug

```
}

public static class Spinner2OnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner2Varialbe = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working perfectly.I didnt found any flaws.
So i suggest you to delete the project,download again and import the project and check whether is it causing problem then?